# create a nested jQuery post in another post callback?

Tags: ajax, jquery

since I'm new in jquery, can you tell me how to redirect a page to another action method ? 
I develop a MVC web application. I use jquery post method to do some validation, and when it return true, it will be redirect page to another one.
My problem is..when when I redirect page using window.location, it's works well in IE (IE 9). but didn't work on firefox & chrome.
So, I try to using jquery post method to redirect page from action method in my controller. I call redirect post method in a jquery post call back.
it is my code :

```
 $.post(posturl, formData, function (result) {
        if (result == 'True') {
            $.post("/Controller/RedirectMethod", {_Action: 'Index', _Controller: 'Home'}, null);
        }
        else
            alert('failed');
    }
    );
```

and this is my RedirectMethod :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RedirectMethod(string _Action, string _Controller)
    {
        return RedirectToAction(_Action, _Controller);
    }
```

so how I should create a nested post in another post callback ?
or there is another way to redirect page ?

thanks,

Comment: `window.location` should work; what were you doing?

Comment: hmm...thanks Alpert, I try to use location.href, and it's works in both, mozilla & chrome. but I dont know why window.location didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do a RedirectToAction inside an Ajax request.

If you need the web page to change to a different location inside the  Ajax response, use window.location as Ben suggested.

One thing to bear in mind is that you'll need to remove the 'HttpPost' action filter.

Comment: "One thing to bear in mind is that you'll need to remove the 'HttpPost' action filter." <- can you tell me more abput it ? thanks